# MongoDB update creates array inside array

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been sitting with this problem for hours and was unable to find solution, so I decided to ask for your help. What is wrong in my query? The problem is it creates array inside array, though my desired result would be simple array.

BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();

```
for (Paths pair : objects)
{
    list.add(new BasicDBObject("path", pair.getPath())
    .append("thumbnailPath, pair.getThumbnailPath()));
}

  BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
    updateCommand.append( "$push", new BasicDBObject( "imageContent", list ) );
    WriteResult result = viewsCollection.update( new BasicDBObject(MongoFieldNames.ID, groupId), updateCommand, true, true );
```

And the result of pushed array is

```
    "imageContent" : [
    [
        {
            "path" : "sadL.png",
            "thumbnailPath" : sad.png"
        },
        {
            "path" : "someImgL.png",
            "thumbnailPath" : "someimg.png"
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$push will create the array property if it doesn't exist.  So in this case, it create the property "imageContent."  then it pushes the value you've given:  an array.  What you want is probably just $set.

Comment: Was this actually what the question asked? Pay careful attention to the variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the code for this because you do not list it. However, the problem here seems to be with the `list` variable, which in all likelihood is **actually** an **array** itself.

So where you want to add an **actual** array, then use the [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/) operator with `$push` instead:

```
BasicDBObject updateCommand = new BasicDBObject();
updateCommand.append( "$push", new BasicDBObject( 
    "imageContent", new BasicDBObject( "$each", list )
));
```

That **will** take an **array/list** and add **all** of the listed items to the existing array, as opposed to "pushing" the **array** into an existing array.

Comment: $pushAll is deprecated but you can use $each with $push  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each

Comment: @evanchooly Correct you are, and amended. But of course the point was that this was *likely* trying to `$push` what was already an array.

Comment: Yep!  to be honest, i didn't know about $pushAll until you mentioned it and then found it was deprecated so TIL ...  :)